# Проблемы парсинга Jsoup при непарных данных

Tags: java, jsoup, парсер

На странице [акций Сильпо](http://silpo.ua/ua/actions/priceoftheweek/?PAGEN_1=2&) есть продукты, у которых отсутствует старая цена. Соответственно мой код работает неправильно и присваивает продукту "Киви" старую цену следующего за ним творога.

```
private ArrayList<Double> findOldPrice(Document doc) {
    ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
    Elements div = doc.getElementsByClass("pr");
    Document document = Jsoup.parse(div.toString());
    Elements elements = document.select("span");
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i += 2) {
        double hrn = Double.parseDouble(elements.get(i).text());
        double kop = Double.parseDouble(elements.get(i + 1).text()) * 0.01;
        double newPrice = hrn + kop;
        list.add(newPrice);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Как можно обойти эту проблему?

Comment: Вы предлагаете за вас написать алгоритм парсинга приведённого вами сайта? Вы пробовали делать проверку на ваше условие и её обрабатывать?

Comment: Я не прошу делать за меня, вы не правильно поняли скорее всего. Я предоставил только часть кода для парсинга одной составляющей. Если внимательно посмотреть на исходный код страницы, то мы увидим, 
что название продукта можно получить из <div class="p10"> или <h3>
новую и старую цены с <div class="price_2014_new"> и <div class="price_2014_old">.
Я это все получаю. Проблема в том, что есть продукты, у которых нет старой цены и я пока не разобрался как попарно добавлять эти данные в список, например  List<productName, newPrice, oldPrice>, значения типа String

Answer (score 1):

Решил данный вопрос следующим образом:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

private static List<String> silpoPages = Arrays.asList("http://silpo.ua/ua/actions/priceoftheweek/?PAGEN_1=1&",
        "http://silpo.ua/ua/actions/priceoftheweek/?PAGEN_1=2&",
        "http://silpo.ua/ua/actions/priceoftheweek/?PAGEN_1=3&");

public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (String silpoPage : silpoPages) {
        Document doc;
        Elements el;
        ArrayList<Element> list = new ArrayList<Element>();
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(silpoPage)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36")
                    .timeout(0)
                    .get();
            el = doc.getElementsByClass("photo");

            String name;
            double newPrice, oldPrice;
            for (Element element : el) {
                name = element.select("h3").text();
                newPrice = Double.parseDouble(element.select("div.price_2014_new").text()) / 100;
                if (!element.select("div.price_2014_old").text().equals("")){
                    oldPrice = Double.parseDouble(element.select("div.price_2014_old").text()) / 100;
                }else {
                    oldPrice = 0;
                }
                System.out.println(name + " " + newPrice + "грн, " + oldPrice + "грн");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Cannot open the site!");
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Возможно не элегантно да и форматирование цен нужно поправить, но возможно кому-то сгодится ;)